# Parametric direct shadow equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry

Find the parametric shadow equation of a straight line passing through the points (0,1,2) and (3,4,0) on the near wall of the paraboloid $ x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 + 4z + 1 = 0. $
The light source is at infinity in the direction of the vector (1,2,3). Determine the type of curve.

Help please, I have never encountered such tasks.

Comment: The shadow lies on an ellipse, which is the intersection between the paraboloid and the plane passing through those two points and parallel to the given vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(0,1,2)$, $B(3,4,0)$, and $\vec{V}(1,2,3)$.

Let $P$ be the plane passing by points $A$ and $B$ and containing points $A'=A+\vec{V}$ and $B'=B+\vec{V}$ (which are in the shadow of line $AB$) ; otherwise said $P$ is the plane passing through $A$ and having normal (orthogonal) vector $$\vec{W}=\vec{AB} \times \vec{V}=\begin{pmatrix}\ \ 13\\-11\\ \ \ 3\end{pmatrix}.$$

thus with equation

$$13x-11y+3z=-5\tag{1}$$

(check that the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ verify equation (1)).

Then the shadow of line $AB$ on the paraboloid $\Pi$ is the intersection $P \cap \Pi$, or more exactly the half of this shadow, on the "closest side" of paraboloid $\Pi$.

You will be able to describe this curve, which is a half-ellipse by taking (1) into account in the equation of paraboloid $\Pi$, by eliminating parameter $z$. In this way, you will get a knowledge of the real shadow, by knowing its projection on plane $xOy$.

Comment: $$ 13x - 11y + 3z = -5;$$
$$ z = \frac{-5 - 13x + 11y}{3}; $$
$$ x^2 + y^2 +\frac{4}{3}(-5-13x + 11y) + 1 = 0; $$
$$ x^2 - \frac{52 x}{3 }+ y^2 + \frac{44 y}{3} - \frac{17}{3} = 0 $$ I get a circle. Am I doing everything right?

Comment: What you have obtained is the equation of the **projection on** $xOy$ of the intersecting ellipse. The projection of an ellipse is in general an ellipse, but it can happen that it is a circle. Now, it remains to obtain the center $(x_0,y_0)$ and the radius $R$ of this circle in order to be able to parameterize this (half) ellipse in the following way $x=x_0+R \cos \theta, y=y_0+R \sin \theta, z=f(R,\theta)$.

Comment: $$(x - \frac{26}{3})^2 + (y + \frac{22}{3})^2 = \frac{1211}{9} $$ => center = $$ (\frac{26}{3}, \frac{-22}{3}),$$  $$ R = \frac{\sqrt{1211}}{3} $$ =>$$ x = \frac{26}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{1211}}{3} cos\eta,  y =  \frac{-22}{3} +  \frac{\sqrt{1211}}{3} sin\eta $$

Comment: $ = f(R, \eta). $ Check, please.

Comment: Your $x_0,y_0,R$ are the good ones (I have checked). For $z=f(R,\theta)$, it suffices to plug the expressions $x=...,y=...$ into equation $z= \frac{-5 - 13x + 11y}{3}$. A pity that coefficients are so complicated...

Comment: Thanks, $ \Large z = f(R, \eta) = \frac{1}{3} (-5 - 13 (\frac{26}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{1211}}{3} cos(\eta)) + 11 (\frac{-22}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{1211}}{3} sin(\eta))) $ Check please. Alternative: $ \large 1/9 (11 \sqrt{1211} sin(\eta) - 13 \sqrt{1211} cos(\eta) - 595) $

Comment: Yes. Of course, you can simplify by grouping some fractions, but it will never be simple looking...